# Append text to each of multiple lines in file

Tags: linux, bash, vim, awk

I have a query which is to be performed on thousands of rows (28,000 odd to be more exact) using a unique identifier.
This is (simplified) the query:

```
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=
```

And there is a file `ids.txt` which contains the ids for the rows the update is to be performed on:

```
10003
10009
....
....
79345
79356
```

The resultant file should be like this:

```
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10003;
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10009;
...
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=79356;
```

**Other** than taking the `ids.txt` file and using vim to form all the 28000 queries using global string substitution, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something simple like `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]*)$/update "table1" set event_type = \'NEW\' where id=\1/' file
               |     write back using \1 as placeholder
             catch digits in the file
```

### Previous answer

I used an approach based on bash loops, whereas it is a bit overkilling. See a related question: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/40596)

Loop like this:

```
while read id
do
   echo "update \"table1\" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=${id};"
done < ids.txt
```

It outputs:

```
$ while read id; do echo "update \"table1\" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=${id};"; done < ids
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10003;
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10009;
...
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=79345;
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=79356;
```

Comment: That was quick! Just needed `where id=${id};";` - the semi-colon at the end of each line to terminate the SQL query.

Comment: Oh that's true, I didn't notice the `;` at the end. I just updated with your version :)

Comment: I downvoted for the reason stated in my answer - writing a shell loop is always the wrong approach when just manipulating text. Unfortunately it's the way most newcomers THINK they should approach the problem so then when they get an answer like that it validates their wrong assumption and sets them back instead of setting them on the right path for how to write shell scripts.

Comment: Good, thanks for showing up @EdMorton. Well, I guess that it is also important to keep things simple, and a `sed` expression is not as easy to read and maintain for a simple requirement like this. But of course, everyone to his own taste.

Comment: If we don't show newcomers the right approach to tackle simple problems, how can we expect them to get it right (or even understand why it's wrong) for complicated problems? Rhetorical, of course.

Comment: But why @EdMorton is so bad for this case?

Comment: Because now the OP thinks that if they have to parse text files it's reasonable to write a shell loop to do it so when they get to the next problem they face that will be their starting point instead of starting with the appropriate tool for the job (probably sed or awk). It also isn't obvious to the OP but the loop you wrote, while it will work for the posted sample input, will not work for other cases - for example it'll fail if the OP tries to apply the same approach with input that contains backslashes or leading spaces and it won't be portable across UNIX systems.

Comment: OK but this is becoming rhetorical also, @EdMorton :) It is bad because it can be bad. Understand I am also kind of newcomer here and I do not see the bad point of reading a file and outputing some parse of it, as the original file does not have to change. Just trying to learn why it is bad, nothing else.

Comment: @fedorui - understood, let me clarify why it's bad: it's not robust, not portable, not scalable, not concise and not efficient, i.e. has none of the desirable attributes of software.

Comment: @EdMorton I just revisited this answer after seeing this question: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/40596). Updated indicating a better aproach, thanks for the comments!!

Comment: Anything shell-related by Stéphane (http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) should be taken as gospel. As noted in the Acknowledgements section of the Shell Scripting Recipes book (http://www.amazon.com/Shell-Scripting-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1590594711#reader_1590594711) NO-ONE knows shell like he does. I didn't know he participated in SO - if anyone has a shell question they should search his answers first!

Comment: @EdMorton yep I agree! He even was the one discovering the shellshock bug. He is very active in Unix & Linux, where in fact you should also go from time to time... And regarding the issue here, I guess that I finally managed to understand the problem you were mentioning one year ago :)

Answer (score 4):

Writing a shell loop is always the wrong approach when just manipulating text.

All you need in this case is a simple sed subsitution:

```
$ cat file
10003
10009
$ sed 's/.*/update "table1" set event_type = '\''NEW'\'' where id=&;/' file
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10003;
update "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=10009;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not global string substitution but from inside vim you could use

```
:%norm Iupdate "table1" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=<ESC>A;
```

where `<ESC>` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/^/update \"table1\" set event_type = 'NEW' where id=/; s/$/;/" id.txt
```

The `-i` makes the change inline (actually changes the file id.txt).

The `s/^/.../` substitutes the start of each line (^) with ...

The `s/$/.../` subsittutes the end of t each line ($) with ...