# Create new text files per line of a txt.txt file in shell

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sorting

I am using bash under linux. How can I take the following txt file and create new text files from it as follows.

txt.txt

```
5#red
2#blue
2#green
2#orange
1#black
```

I would like to be able to create a new file per line and insert some tags resulting in the following format for each new file, also NAME the new txt file using the last word of the line...

red.txt

```
<some tag> 5 </some tag> <some-other-tag> #red </some-other-tag>
```

and so on per line.

Comment: Your input looked a bit weird. I cleaned it, but please cross check if it still is the way it should.

Comment: i would suggest to write something first and then add what you tried to question

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using a while loop :

```
while IFS="#" read -r int color; do
    echo "<some tag> $int </some tag> <some-other-tag> #$color </some-other-tag>" > "$color.txt"
done < file
```

Comment: I was about to post something related and then I remembered [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20123199/1983854) with Ed Morton :D

Comment: Yes but no double quotes needed here. If needed, a solution is to use ascii representation instead : `\042`

Comment: Well the discussion wasn't about the quotes, but about parsing a file with a bash loop.

Comment: Maybe readability is better than winning nano seconds in this case, up to the OP =) Depends of the size of the input too.

Comment: @sputnick check your code, it doesn't make a file for the last line of the sample file. For example, if given the file above, the colour black will not have a file.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
awk -F"#" '
   {printf "<some tag> %d </some tag> \
            <some-other-tag> #%s </some-other-tag>\n",
            $1, $2 > $2".txt"}' file
                   ^
                   redirection to a file after 2nd field's name
```

This `awk` gets the 1st and 2nd fields from the input based on `#` as separator. Then, it prints the desired output... in a file called `$2.txt`, that is, the name of the 2nd field together with `.txt`.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F"#" '{printf "<some tag> %d </some tag> <some-other-tag> #%s </some-other-tag>\n", $1, $2 > $2".txt"}' a
```

And now we have many `*.txt` files, for example:

```
$ cat red.txt
<some tag> 5 </some tag> <some-other-tag> #red </some-other-tag>
```